# How do you reliably share video between iPhone and Mac

Tags: icloud, photos, airdrop

Sometimes my videos upload from my iPhone to iCloud and then download to the Mac, sometimes they don't. It's maybe a 50% chance it'll sync within a day.  (I don't know if this is normal, I am curious about that?)

When I try to manually share the video from iPhone to Mac using AirDrop — on my phone, tapping on the Mac icon/circle in AirDrop sometimes shares and sometimes gets stuck on "waiting".

This issue slows down my workflow so much it drives me crazy.  So I wonder if anyone can tell me how to do either of the following:

- Get photos and videos syncing reliably and quickly
- How to get AirDrop to work every day?

Comment: Sorry to hear about your troubles. Have you tried importing your videos by cable?

Comment: I honestly hadn't thought of that. That definitely solves the problem temporarily. Thanks!